# Constrain type to allow addition/subtraction operations (+/-) in C#

Tags: c#, types

Is this possible?

```
public interface Foo<TBar>
  where TBar : (can use the '+' and '-' operators)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a type `Foo` that overloads those two operators and then constrain your generic type to it.  You cannot however constrain your generic parameter to require that any arbitrary type overloads such operators on an ad-hoc basis.

Comment: Trying to understand, you're saying you can't constrain the generic type to a type that implements the operators? How is this different than `Interface IRepository<T> where T : ModelBase` ?

Comment: @hometoast, you can certainly do that -- you can constrain the type parameter to a *specific* type that overloads those operators.  My point is that the OP seems to want to restrict the type to **any** type so *long* as it overloads those operators.  I am emphasizing that the latter is not possible.

Comment: Makes sense. What about constraining a generic type to a double, float, int, etc. (i.e. value types that can use '+' and '-' but do not overload them). I suppose you can't constrain a generic type to a value type.

Comment: @ken, correct, the valid constraints are the literals `class`, `new()`, and `struct`, in addition to types identifying classes or interfaces (not specific enum or other value types).  However, using `struct` you could constrain it to *all* value types -- but since some value types do not overload those operators, it would not allow you to utilize the `+` and `-` operators on values of type `TBar`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and No.  A generic parameter can only be constrained to

- Implement an inerface
- Have an accessible parameterless constructor (`new()`)
- Have a particular base type
- Be a struct / class

The only one of these which is useful for `+` and `-` operators is the base type.  So if the base type contains these operators you can constrain your `TBar` to also implement them.

However this doesn't work in the general sense.  No matter what base type you choose it will fail to work with the types which are most commonly used with `+` and `-`.  Namely `int`, `double`, `string`, etc ... because they inherit from `ValueType` which doesn't have this constraint

Answer (score 2):

You can overload the operators:

```
public static TBar operator +(TBar c1, TBar c2) 
{
   return ... // do the math
}
```

Comment: Ok, you want to overload addition for something that is not known to have such property. return c1+c2 ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

You could, in theory, constraint TBar to of a type that implements those operators, but operators are static, they're not inherited.

Which means that you would effectively constrain your type to be *only* the base type, in which case you could drop generics altogether.

And no, you can't constrain your TBar generic parameter to be "any type that implements those operators", it's just not available in the language.