# casting string to IEquatable<Object> causes error

Tags: c#, .net

while trying to compile following code

```
IEquatable<Object> value = "test";
```

it causes this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IEquatable<object>'
```

but string implements `IEquatable<String>`

MyCode:

```
    public class Equals : Validation
    {
        public IEquatable<Object> Value { get; set; }

        public Equals(IEquatable<Object> value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public override bool Validate(Object value)
        {
            return Value.Equals(value);
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
        [Equals("test")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: `IEquatable<String>` is not `IEquatable<object>`

Comment: Google Covariance and Contravariance and you should find all the info you need or check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806170/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-sharp

Comment: @KevinGosse but String can be casted to object

Comment: @Sahandevs It doesn't mean that casting the generic type would be safe. Let's take a simple example: `List<string>`. By following your reasoning, it should be castable to `List<object>`. Therefore, I should be able to add an `int` inside of it (since int is castable to object). You see how unsafe it can get. That's why only interfaces that are explicitly marked as covariant can be casted that way. This is not the case for `IEquatable`

Comment: @Rango is there is anyway to use generics like java?

Comment: @Rango like IEquatable<?>

Comment: @Sahandevs what's your real problem ? what do you need `IEquatable<object>` for ?

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim i updated my post

Comment: In this precise case, you don't need `IEquatable<T>`. Just store an `Object` and call `Equals(object)` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals

Comment: @KevinGosse but in case of Max Or Min there is no compareTo method for object and i have to use IComparable

Comment: This is fundamentally unsafe, if it were allowed you could do: `IComparable<object> comp = "test"; comp(3);`. You can either use the non-generic interfaces such as `IComparable`, create an unsafe wrapper implementing `IEquatable<object>` around some `IEquatable<T>` implementation, or use reflection/dynamic typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String implements `IEquatable<String>` and not `IEquatable<Object>`
So `IEquatable<String> value = "test"` should work

Comment: i cannot change the generic type is there anyway to convert these two? string can be casted to object

Comment: No it is not possible. You can cast string to object but you cant cast `IEquatable<string>` to `IEquatable<object>` because string inherits object but  `IEquatable<string>` does not inherit `IEquatable<object>`

Answer (score 0):

for your code to work, you can not insert into an object the value of a string so that it works use:

```
IEquatable<string> value ="test";
```